# Not saving radio button that was originally disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a asp.net web forms application, and there are multiple questions that have yes/no questions, with subquestions that have radio buttons for answers. On page load all sub-question answers (radio buttons) are disabled (unless they had been previously saved). When you click "yes", the buttons are no longer disabled (using jquery) and you can answer the subquestions. When you hit submit, it prompts you to answer unanswered questions and does not save the ones you just filled in. However, if you fill in the same radio buttons on this 2nd load, then everything saves fine.

Is this a problem with page life cycle? Does it think the radio buttons are not selected because on page load they are disabled? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: We'll need to see some code. For sure the jQuery.

Comment: Just wondering, cant you use AutoPostBack for Radio buttons and check if postback and enable other radio button if _rdo1_ was yes? that way you dont have to reply on JS for that part.